# Why the loss still repeat?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I try to run 10 epoch, but the value is strange and will not change.

The output after 10 epoch is exactly the same.

I use mnist dataset', 3 layers and 128 batch to train my model.

output

[image]

my code

```
(x, y), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# to tensor
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32)/255
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.int32)
 
train_db = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(128)

# [b, 784] -> [b, 256] -> [b, 128] -> [b, 10] 
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([784, 256], stddev=0.1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([256, 128], stddev=0.1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([128]))
w3 = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([128, 10], stddev=0.1))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

lr = 1e-3

for epoch in range(10):
    print('---', epoch, '---')
    for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train_db):
        x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28*28])
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            h1 = tf.nn.relu(x@w1+b1)
            h2 = tf.nn.relu(h1@w2+b2)
            y_out = h2@w3+b3

            # compute loss
            y_onehot = tf.one_hot(y, depth=10)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_onehot-y_out))

        # compute gradient
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, [w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3])

        # update 
        w1.assign_sub(w1 - lr*grads[0]) 
        b1.assign_sub(b1 - lr*grads[1]) 
        w2.assign_sub(w2 - lr*grads[2]) 
        b2.assign_sub(b2 - lr*grads[3]) 
        w3.assign_sub(w3 - lr*grads[4]) 
        b3.assign_sub(b3 - lr*grads[5]) 

        if step%100 == 0:
            print(step, '\tloss:\t', float(loss))
```

Comment: Please share the full code if you want people to be able to reproduce this error and try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: The above is all.

Comment: @lolo why are you using `assign_sub` and then performing the subtraction within the argument of that function?  I thought it was supposed to do that for you by construction: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign_sub